# What does it mean that a morphism in a category is fully determined by another morphism

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

My question is taking place more specifically in a tensor category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\phi,\psi)$ (I will denote this category with $\mathcal{C}$ going forward) where $\otimes:\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ is a *bifunctor*, $\phi$ is the *associator* and $\psi$ is the *commutator*.

Now, let $U$ be an identity object in $\mathcal{C}$. Then we have an *equivalence of categories* $X \leadsto U \otimes X$ for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

Furthermore, we have a unique morphism $l_X:X \to U \otimes X$. I want to understand what it means to say that "due to the equivalence of categories $X \leadsto U \otimes X$, this map is **fully determined** by $1 \otimes l_X:U \otimes X \to U \otimes (U \otimes X)$.

We note that $X \leadsto U \otimes X$ and $U \otimes X \leadsto U \otimes (U \otimes X)$. But what does it mean to say that the map $l_X$ is fully determined by $1 \otimes l_X$, and why is this the case?

My question is motivated by page $5$ here: https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2018.pdf

Comment: For context, where does the claim that the morphism is "fully determined" come from? In general, the morphism $l_X : X \to U \otimes X$ is not unique. But perhaps you are using a different notion of "tensor category" than me. Could you point to the definition you are using? Also, it doesn't make sense to say that there's an equivalence of categories between $X$ and $U \otimes X$, because they are objects of a category. One would usually call them isomorphic. Where does your notation come from, so we can better understand the question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll add a reference.

Comment: Actually, $l_X$ is unique in the categories of interest in the reference I gave. See proposition $1.3.a$. But I believe a friend showed me why, I can post an answer later when I have figured out all the details, hopefully.

Comment: Regarding $X \leadsto U \otimes X$ being an equivalence of categories, I suppose they mean $F,G:\mathcal{C} \leftrightarrows \mathcal{C}$ so that $GF(X) \cong G(U \otimes X) \cong X$ and $FG(U \otimes X) \cong F(X) \cong X$.

Comment: @Ben123 You misunderstood varkor's comment. "Then we have an equivalence of categories $X \mapsto U \otimes X$ for every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$" does not make sense; what makes sense is to say "there is an equivalence of categories that maps every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to $U \otimes X$" (it is perhaps what you meant, I don't know, but anyway it is not what you wrote).

Comment: Yes, that was bad wording. I meant the functor which we can denote by $U \otimes (-)$